# R is not saving out the table consistently into integer values

Tags: r, output

For some reason (it's never done this before), R is not saving out files in the correct way.

The file needs to save out as integer numbers regardless of how big/small the number is. R is doing that for some values, but not for others. Remaking the file just changes what value is contracted.

This is what the incorrect file looks like:

```
1   834101  248830000
1   4e+06   4005000 #incorrect line
1   4955000 4965000
```

This is the code I used to get it:

```
write.table(outtable, 'outtable.txt', sep = "\t",
            row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F)
```

This is what I need the file to look like:

```
1   834101  248830000
1   4000000 4005000
1   4955000 4965000
```

How do I stop R writing out the '4000000' or '6000000' as 4e+06/6e+06?

I'd be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Run `options(scipen = 99)` in your R console and try again.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you for taking the time to answer! This works :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Change `options("scipen")` to something bigger; I believe it defaults to `0`, so something 2 or more *here* will work:

   ```r
   dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), V2 = c(834101, 4000000, 4955000), V3 = c(248830000L, 4005000L, 4965000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
   options(scipen = 2) # anything 2 or higher will work, 99 is fine too
   write.table(dat, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
   # 1 834101  248830000
   # 1 4000000 4005000
   # 1 4955000 4965000
   ```

   (Larger ints might need higher versions of `scipen=`, note that from [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html), this number relates to the number of digits "width".)
2. Format as strings before writing.

   ```r
   str(dat)
   # 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
   #  $ V1: int  1 1 1
   #  $ V2: num  834101 4000000 4955000
   #  $ V3: int  248830000 4005000 4965000
   dat[] <- lapply(dat, sprintf, fmt = "%0i")
   str(dat)
   # 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
   #  $ V1: chr  "1" "1" "1"
   #  $ V2: chr  "834101" "4000000" "4955000"
   #  $ V3: chr  "248830000" "4005000" "4965000"
   write.table(dat, sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
   # 1 834101  248830000
   # 1 4000000 4005000
   # 1 4955000 4965000
   ```

   This has the side-effect of either modifying your table or requiring you to have two copies of it; over to you if that's a problem.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer! modifying the table is no problem whatsoever